# JSX map only the first object in array

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm curious on how to only render the first object in an array using `.map` in JSX.

```
{this.state.data.map(data =>
    <span className="fooBar">
        <a href={data.foo}>{data.bar}</a>
    </span>
)}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to just not use `.map` at all!

```
<span className="fooBar">
    <a href={this.state.data[0].foo}>{this.state.data[0].bar}</a>
</span>
```

`.map` will always go over every object in an array - there's no way to break out of it early.

Comment: Is it possible to offset this? Like if you want the rest of the data wrapped in a different div for example.

Comment: @budji: For the rest of the data, you could just slice the array: `this.state.data.slice(1).map(x => ...)`

Comment: Not working still it's  this.state.data[0] is undefined

Comment: If there is a chance that `this.state.data[0]` will be undefined, you must handle that in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Map is designed to call every element in an array applying a transformation.

If you just want to render the first then you'd be better to either explicitly call the first element this.state.data[0] or use a library that supports a method like [head](https://lodash.com/docs#head).

**Lodash Example**

```
const link = _.head(this.state.data);
<span className="fooBar">
  <a href={link.href}>{link.title}</a>
</span>
```

Comment: I am new in reactjs. how can i use lodash in react.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works correctly.

```
{data.map((data, i) =>
    <span className="fooBar">
        <a href={data.foo}>{data.bar}</a>
    </span>
)[0]}
```